# How to find key by its first letters and print key and value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictionary that updates by users input (first while). I want to print all key + value from dictionary starting with letter(letters) that user enters in second input. How i can do that?

```
r = {}
while (True):
    print('Enter key (empty enter - exit)')
    k = input()
    if k == '':
        break
    print('Enter value')
    v = input()
    r[k] = v
print(r)

s = input('Key: ')
while s != '':
    print(s, r.get(s.lower()))
    s = input('new try: ')
```

Now i only get key and value if user enters whole key
But i want to print all keys that are located in dictionary starting with users input

Answer (score 0):

try to create a new list using list comprehension and condition predicate startswith
for example

```
r = { "abc" : "adfadsa", "abd" : "adfadfag", "cde" : "dafdfadsf"}
[(a,b) for a,b in r.items() if a.startswith("ab")]
```

will give output

```
[('abc', 'adfadsa'), ('abd', 'adfadfag')]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First,get all keys start with input:

   `keys = r.keys().filter(lambda x:x.startwith(input))`
2. Second,print key and value:

   `fot key in keys:
   print (key,r[key])`